# How can I manage communication from multiple windows forms applications using MODBUS protocol?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, modbus

I am trying to implement a module in an application that handles communication with a PLC or multiple PLCs.  I am currently using a c# library implementation to interface with the mbserver application found here http://mbserver.tripod.com/ .  I am using a serial port to handle the commucation.  The problem I am having is that in the event of an unplug of the serial cable my application is not able to recover from it unless I use a configuration application provided by the same company.  I am looking into MBLogic software but it all written in python.  Other than that I don't really have too many ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have used OPC in the past to communicate with PLCs:

http://www.opcfoundation.org/

They have a .NET driver under their downloads section.